# No funciona paginacion en consulta entre fechas en laravel

Tags: date, laravel-8, paginación

Estoy Realizando una consulta donde me trae registros con fecha inicio y fecha fin. Pero a la hora de darle siguiente o el numero siguiente en este caso el 2 no me muestra registros.

Esta es la función del controlador donde  recibo los inputs del formulario y devuelvo la vista con los registros entre fechas

```
public function totalSeguimientosFechas(Request $request){

    $reporte=Seguimiento::select('*')->with('paciente')->with('user')
    ->where('estado','A')
    ->whereBetween('fecha',
    [Carbon::parse($request->fecha_ini)->toDateString(),
    Carbon::parse($request->fecha_fin)->toDateString(),
    ])
    ->paginate(7);

    return view('reportes.fechas', compact('reporte'));
}
```

Esta es la vista donde muestro los registros

```
@extends('layouts.template')
@section ('contenido')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <h3>
            Listado de Seguimientos por fecha
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div id="response">
            @if (Session::has('message'))
                <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable text-center">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                    {{ Session::get('message') }}
                </div>
            @endif
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive tableFixHead">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-sm"
                style="width:100%">
                <thead class="text-center thead-dark">

                    <th>
                        Idendificacion
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Paciente
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Abuso Sexual
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Autoestima
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Fecha Creacion
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        No Seguimiento
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Psicologo Encargado
                    </th>

                </thead>
                <tbody >
                @foreach ($reporte as $seg)
                    <tr class="text-center" >
                        <td>
                            {{ $seg->paciente->identificacion }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ $seg->paciente->nombres }} {{ $seg->paciente->apellidos }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ $seg->abuso_sexual }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ $seg->autoestima }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ $seg->fecha }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ $seg->numero }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ $seg->user->nombres }} {{ $seg->user->apellidos }}
                        </td>
                        
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                @endforeach
            </table>
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ $reporte->render() }}
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
@endsection
```

Este es el resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando le doy click en la paginacion 2 se pierden los registros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo solucione guardando los inputs y pasandosela desde el controlador a la vista y agregando el appends en paginacion.

```
public function totalSeguimientosFechas(Request $request){


        $fecha_ini = $request->get('fecha_ini');
        $fecha_fin = $request->get('fecha_fin');
        
        $reporte=Seguimiento::select('*')->with('paciente')->with('user')
        ->where('estado','A')
        ->whereBetween('fecha',
        [Carbon::parse($request->fecha_ini)->toDateString(),
        Carbon::parse($request->fecha_fin)->toDateString(),
        ])
        // ->get();
        ->paginate(7);

        // dd($reporte);

        return view('reportes.fechas', compact('reporte','fecha_ini','fecha_fin'));
    }
```

en la vista

```
    {{-- paginacion con variable  de busqueda para que no se pierda al paginar --}}
    {{ $reporte->appends(['fecha_ini'=>$fecha_ini,'fecha_fin'=>$fecha_fin])->links() }}
```